# Type hinting for dynamically created methods

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

When writing a Python script in PyCharm, if I create a named tuple like:

```
from collections import namedtuple
nt = namedtuple('my_named_tuple', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
x = nt(1, 2, 3)
```

If I leave out any of the required arguments (specified when creating the `namedtuple`) PyCharm will recognize this and highlight it in the code:

[image]

And similarly if I add too many arguments:

[image]

I would like to understand how this is achieved. Is it something that can be done in code and if so how? Or is it simply because PyCharm knows to find the correct number of args for a namedtuple?

If I create my own kind of dynamically created type with variable number of `__init__` args then I wont get this effect in PyCharm, at least not the way that I am doing it, ie. for example:

```
def my_dynamic_type(name: str, args: tuple[str, ...]):
    exec(f'def __init__({", ".join(("self",) + args)}): ...')
    return type(name, (), {'__init__': locals()['__init__']})


mdt = my_dynamic_type('my_type', ('a', 'b', 'c'))

mdt(1, 2, 3)  # works

# WRONG NUMBER OF ARGS BUT NO HIGHLIGHTING:
mdt(1, 2, 3, 4)  # TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
mdt(1, 2)  # TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
```

Is there some way to create a custom type in Python which will be treated similar to `namedtuple` while typing code in PyCharm?

Comment: it's possible jetbrains make their own proprietary analysis tools and we'll never actually know how PyCharm does it. I appreciate that we can usefully speculate, however

Comment: That's absolutely what PyCharm has to do. There's nothing *static* about what `namedtuple` does, so a type checker has to be programmed to understand what `namedtuple` does. (I'm not sure how smart it is, but you might try something as simple as `y = namedtuple; nt = y('my_named_tuple', ('a', 'b', 'c'))` and see if PyCharm still knows that `nt` should take 3 arguments.)

Comment: @chepner Tried it and it works just fine

Comment: OK, it's a little smarter than I gave it credit for :) But it's still basically just noting that `y` is another name for `namedtuple`, which it is hard-coded to know about.

Comment: What makes you think you need to use `exec` in the first place?

Comment: @chepner nothing really, except that it is the only way I can dynamically create a function which only actually takes n arguments, alternative would be to create a function which takes `*args` and then dynamically require that `len(args) == n` at runtime. Either way nether solution will give me "namedtuple"-like behavior out of the box...

Comment: `namedtuple` is surely special cased by PyCharm.
The best you can possibly do is imitating the behaviour of dataclasses. Since Python3.11 there's [dataclass_transform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.dataclass_transform) which enabled creating dataclass-like classes that are understood by type checkers.

Answer (score -5):

What do you think about avoiding "dynamic defined namedtuples"? This can guide our code to total chaos.

I think you should use dataclasses or, if you are focused on namedtuples, subclass `NamedTuple` from `typing`.

Something like this:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Foo(NamedTuple):
  bar: int

foo = Foo(5)
```